# I can’t predict the output of tellg() in a programme

Tags: c++

How does the get pointer move after reading an object in a data file.for instance,if the get pointer starts at ‘0’th byte,then when the statement “file.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s))”gets executed, will the get pointer move to the next object in the file automatically.
Thank you.

Comment: If you have opened the file in binary mode, then reading N bytes will advance the get pointer by N bytes. Whether that is the 'next object' or not depends entirely on what your objects are and what is in the file.

Comment: Suggestion: spend several hours in reading [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), then read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Stackoverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website. Please provide some [mre] in your question

Comment: I recommend against storing the binary representation of objects in files to begin with. Rather, define a format with which a file can be represented (either a compressed binary or something human readable like JSON or an INI file) and read in objects like that then *convert* them to an object in memory. The byte representation of an object may not capture all of its state (e.g., binary repr of `class foo { std::string bar; }` won't necessarily give you the data stored in `bar`), and even if it does the representation may vary from implementation to implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use

```
ifstream fin("name-of-file");
ofstream fout("name-of-file");
```

fin is the file-variable and you can use any name for it, just it need to be unique. Same for fout.
Then, you can read variables from files and write in files.

```
fin>>x;
fout<<x;
```

By the way, you need to include  library.